# I would like a RAM recommendation for HPE ML110 G9 E5-2603v4

Tags: linux, server

According to [HPE](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c05226549), the model HPE ML110 G9 processor E5-2603v4, supports RAM 16 GB up to 1866 MHz

[image]

According to the [QuickSpecs](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04545452) of this model, it comes by default with 8 GB RAM 2400 Mhz

[image]

According to the dmidecode command on linux, this server provides the following information:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17
```

out

```
Speed: 2400 MT/s
Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
```

[image]

But this command is somewhat [confusing with the information it provides](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521434/dmidecode-for-ram-info-which-speed-is-real-speed-info)

What I want to know is that if I can upgrade the RAM of this server to:

16GB (1x16) DDR4 ECC RDIMM 2R (1866 or 2133 or 2400 or 3200 Mhz)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your HP link :

- Install DIMMs only if the corresponding processor is installed.
- To maximize performance, it is recommended to balance the total memory capacity between all installed processors and load the channels similarly whenever possible.
- White DIMM slots denote the first slot to be populated in a channel.
- Place the DIMMs with the highest number of ranks in the white slot when mixing DIMMs of different ranks on the same channel.
- **Do not mix RDIMMs or LRDIMMs.**
- **Quad rank RDIMMs are not supported** in HPE ProLiant ML110 Gen9 servers.
- Quad rank LRDIMMs are capable of up to three DIMMs per channel.
- RDIMMs operating at 1.2 V.
- **DIMMs of different speeds may be mixed in any order; the server will select a common optimal speed.**
- **The maximum memory speed is a function of the memory type, memory configuration, and processor model.**
- The maximum memory capacity is a function of the memory type and number of installed processors.
- To realize the performance memory capabilities listed in this document, HPE SmartMemory is required.
- There are four (4) channels per processor There are two (2) DIMM slots for each memory channel; eight (8) total slots. Memory channels1 and 3 consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are furthest from the processor. Memory channel 2 and 4 consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are closest to the processor.

> What I want to know is that if I can upgrade the RAM of this server to: `16GB (1x16) DDR4 ECC RDIMM 2R (1866 or 2133 or 2400 or 3200 Mhz)`

yes, but using only one RDIMM (you say 1x16) you will not be *maximizing performance*

Comment: Very good analysis, but only answered part of my question. did not mention the frequency

Comment: DIMMs of different speeds may be mixed in any order; the server will select a common optimal speed

Comment: buy either... 1866 or 2133 or 2400 or 3200 Mhz,  the ram will downclock automatically... if 2400mhz is the highest supported by the server for example a 3200mhz DIMM will downclock to 2400 (or 2133 or 1866).  buy whatever's cheapest, probably 2400 or 3200 these days.

Comment: the smartest thing to do may be to simply email HP, being a proliant *server* ask them directly specifically on the RAM before you buy it for confirmation if it will work.  Hp, dell, whoever else, is pretty good customer service wise on an email like that.